# Boost Graph Library, Erdos Renyi Generator. Graphs always have same number of edges

Tags: boost, network-programming, graph-theory, boost-graph, random-seed

I'm trying to generate Erdos-Renyi graphs using boost graph library.

In the code below, which is taken from
[The Boost 1.72 documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/doc/sorted_erdos_renyi_gen.html)

the **networks always have the same number of edges** (they should not, for particular p values).  I have tried using different random seeds to no avail.

Thanks for any help.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/erdos_renyi_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/random/linear_congruential.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::adjacency_list<> Graph;
typedef boost::sorted_erdos_renyi_iterator<boost::minstd_rand, Graph> ERGen;

int main()
{
  boost::minstd_rand gen;
  // Create graph with 100 nodes and edges with probability 0.05
  Graph g(ERGen(gen, 100, 0.05), ERGen(), 100);
  cout << num_edges(g)<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a randomized seed:

```
boost::minstd_rand gen(std::random_device{}());
```

The nature of PRNG is that they generate deterministic output from a given state.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/674863fc4f312246)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/erdos_renyi_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/random/linear_congruential.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::adjacency_list<> Graph;
typedef boost::sorted_erdos_renyi_iterator<boost::minstd_rand, Graph> ERGen;

int main() {
    boost::minstd_rand gen(std::random_device{}());
    // Create graph with 100 nodes and edges with probability 0.05
    Graph g(ERGen(gen, 100, 0.05), ERGen(), 100);
    cout << num_edges(g) << endl;
}
```

Prints, e.g.

```
515
491
518
511
```